# vpython GdkGLExt-WARNING in Fedora 17

Tags: python, linux, fedora, yum, vpython

I have `Python 2.7.3` installed in Fedora 17. I installed `vpython` and I run the following python script

```
from visual import *
a = sphere(color = color.red)
```

I get a brief vpython window outline but no image, and the following error output

```
(python:3538): GdkGLExt-WARNING **: Cannot open \u000f

(python:3538): GdkGLExt-WARNING **: Cannot open ЇO\xa4O\u007f

(python:3538): glibmm-ERROR **: 
unhandled exception (type std::exception) in signal handler:
what: Unable to get extension function: glCreateProgramObjectARB even though the      extension is advertised.

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I have used Ubuntu in the past and have gotten rid of the same error by installing `libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev`, this completely fixed it. What is the package in the `yum` repository I need to install to fix this? If that is unavailable, what else can I do?

Answer (score -1):

gtkglextmm-devel

You can use yum provides to determine which package a file belongs to:

```
$ yum provides *libgtkglextmm*

Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto
gtkglextmm-1.2.0-15.fc18.i686 : C++ wrapper for GtkGlExt
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2.so.0.0.0
Provides    : libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2.so.0
Filename    : /usr/lib/libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2.so.0

gtkglextmm-devel-1.2.0-15.fc18.i686 : Development tools for gtkglextmm 
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2.la
Filename    : /usr/lib/libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2.so
Provides    : libtool(/usr/lib/libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2.la)
```

For brevity I'm only showing the i686 output.  You will also see the x86_64 listings.